# Asp.net Web Api: How to map request body directly into C# input in controller for AMP XHR POST request?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, amp-html

```
I have AMP form with name input and submit button. The code looks like:

    <form method="post" id="lead-form" action-xhr="//localhost/api/stockleads1/" target="_top">
                            <h2 class="text-black text-bold padding-bottom10">Fill in your details</h2>
                            <div class="position-rel width80">
                                <input type="text"
                                       name="name"
                                       class="form-control padding-right20 padding-left20 margin-bottom20"
                                       placeholder="Name"
                                       id="txtUserName"
                                       required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="width80">
                               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange btn-full-width text-uppercase buyer-pro-btn" id="btnSend" value="Submit">
                           </div>
    </form>
```

I have create ASP.NET WEB API to save this data on server side.
The code looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/stockleads1")]
public IHttpActionResult Post1()
{
  string name = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["name"];
}
```

This works fine. But I don't want to read request body parameters like this, instead want to directly map them i.e.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/stockleads1")]
public IHttpActionResult Post1([FromBody]Lead lead)
{
  string name = lead.name; //lead class has name property.
}
```

Once I do this change, the request starts coming to this controller action but lead is null.

Currently I have added following to support multi part form data:
                         config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data"));

Any help here? What should I try to enable this AMP XHR to C# Object Request body mapping?

Comment: as the lead object comes from the post body, you need to assign the "Lead" parameter with the FromBody-Attribute: "[FromBody] Lead lead"

Comment: alredy done, not working

Comment: So I assume you are getting a 404 response? I don't know if it will make a difference but your Type has a `Name` property with capital "N" and your form has a field with `name`, lower case.

Comment: Tried this as well.. not working.. I am getting 415..

Comment: That is media type not supported. What is with the `application/csp-report"? That's not a mime type. A csp report is still json.

Comment: Not sure, what is that. But I got some clue here. I added             config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data")); AND now I am able to get debug point on controller method that accepts lead in request body BUT it's NULL object

Comment: Why do you feel you need to add any different media types at all?

Comment: @Crowcoder: I have modified the problem. Any clue now?

Comment: Don't add a JsonFormatter unless you really have a custom one. Web API already knows how to deal with the common ones. And what is "Dummy"? There is something going on that you haven't shown.

Comment: @Crowcoder: sorry, for the confusion. I was just trying to rename Lead object and posted it here:
The actual error in console was : {"Message":"The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
"ExceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Lead' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",

This was removed when I added:
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data"));

Comment: Don't manually add a SupportedMediatype. Take that code right out.

Comment: What should I solve to do the problem? If I remove this code, it gives an error for multipart form data

Comment: What content type does AMP use by default? I'm not familiar with AMP. Can you configure it to use `application/json`?